# Is Wolfram Alpha Wrong on the least common multiple

Tags: algebra-precalculus, least-common-multiple

Question - Find the LCM of $x+5,5-x,x^2-25$.
[image]

I feel like Wolfram Alpha doesn't have the right answer here and I am wondering if I am missing something. I think the answer is $(x+5)(5-x)(x-5)$ like Symbolab says. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: $x-5=-(5-x).{}.$ Wolfram is correct

Comment: Perhaps you’re confusion lies with the fact that $5-x = -(x-5)$. Hence the only prime factors that need to be considered are $x+5$ and $x-5$ since $x^2-25 = (x+5)(x-5)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see it now. I really appreciate the help. I wasn't seeing it at first but now I do :)

Comment: So is it true that Symbolab's answer in my second photo is not really the LCM?

Comment: That's right, it isn't the LCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram's answer looks right to me. It is definitely a common multiple:

$$ \begin{align} (x+5)(x-5) &= (x-5)\cdot (x+5) \\
&= (-x-5)\cdot (5-x) \\
&= 1\cdot (x^2-25)\end{align} $$
and it has to be a *least* common multiple, because nothing with degree less than $2$ can be a nontrivial multiple of $x^2-25$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see it now. I really appreciate the help. I wasn't seeing it at first but now I do :) So is it true that Symbolab's answer in my second photo is not really the LCM?

Comment: @MathIsHard: Yeah, it looks (from your screenshot) like it has problems with non-monic factors.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram is correct. Note that $x+5$ and $5-x$ clearly divide the output given, and $x^2-25 = (x-5)(x+5)$ also divides the output.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see it now. I really appreciate the help. I wasn't seeing it at first but now I do :) So is it true that Symbolab's answer in my second photo is not really the LCM?